# Can I remove "have to" in this sentence?

Tags: questions

What is the meaning of these sentences? What is the difference between them?

> Why ***did you have to*** name me after stew?
>   Why ***did  you***  name me after stew?

Comment: Probably you were named after stew because your parents didn’t want to make a decision on an empty stomach.

Comment: @tchrist I have to admit, I'm now curious what the name in question is.

Comment: @WendiKidd Stuart Little.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Without *have to*, the question is just that: a question, seeking an answer.

> Why did you name me after stew? *Burgoo* is a very odd name! Where did it come from?

Adding *have to* implies that the question is 'rhetorical', and its intent is to protest:

> Why did you have to name me after stew? I hate that name! and I hate burgoo, too! You could at least have named me after something I like, like bouillabaisse.

Comment: Had I travelled into the future to find out what kind of foods you would grow to like, young man, I certainly could have...  Not that I would when you take an attitude like that! ;) +1

Comment: @WendiKidd I still think it's very odd of you to have named your son *Burgoo*. What kind of Foxfire hippie are you, anyway?

Comment: Oi! What's wrong with Foxfire Kits? Oh. Hippies. You said hippies.